# Why does DataContext.SubmitChanges() Exist?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not sure if this goes here or on Stack Overflow, but I figure someone here might know it.

Why did the developers of LINQ decide that not only do you need

```
ctx.InsertOnSubmit(item);
```

but you also need

```
ctx.Items.SubmitChanges();
```

Did they do this so you could execute several queries on one trip to the database or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure about LINQ but i would say that the seperation is based on transaction control. You apply any number of updates, inserts or deletes. That are then held as a unit of work, then once you've finished your changes you simply commit them to the database as a single action or roll all of the changes back, maintaining the integrity of your database.